# Process sentinels don't run during init in GUI Emacs

Tags: process, gui-emacs, async

Ok, this issue I'm running into seems pretty weird. I'm running an async process during init and I have set a process sentinel to tell me when it exits. This works fine in terminal Emacs but in GUI Emacs the process sentinel never runs.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
(setq my/test-flag nil)
(defun my/test-sentinel (proc &optional _change)
  (setq my/test-flag t))
(let* ((name "test")
       (buf (generate-new-buffer (concat "*" name "*")))
       (proc (let ((process-connection-type nil))
               (apply #'start-process name buf "sleep" '("3")))))
  (set-process-sentinel proc #'my/test-sentinel)
  (while (not my/test-flag)
    (sleep-for 0.05)))
```

If you put this in `init.el` and run terminal Emacs, it will hang for 3 seconds as expected before continuing on. GUI Emacs, on the other hand, will hang forever, indicating that `my/test-sentinel` is never run, even though the process does finish after 3 seconds.

Background info:

- I am using Emacs 27.1 from the Arch Linux repositories.
- I failed to reproduce this on macOS using the `emacs` Cask.
- Replacing `sleep-for` with `accept-process-output` gives the same result.
- If the snippet is run by the user after init, the sentinel runs as expected in GUI Emacs.
- This issue arose while debugging use of `async-wait` from the `async` package during init.

Comment: I put the code in the end of my init.el then restart my Emacs (Emacs Mac Port), it does not hang forever and after Emacs finishes startup, `my/test-flag` is `t`.

Comment: I see the same result as @xuchunyang with GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars) of 2020-08-12, on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I see the same behavior as @PythonNut on emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.13, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2020-04-23 (a self-built version). I did `emacs -q -l foo.el` where `foo.el` contains just the code above.

Comment: I also tried toggling `debug-on-quit` and added a debugging print of `(process-list)` in the loop: the test process appears in that output for as long as I wait: after pressing `C-g` I call `process-list` and it returns nil.

Comment: I just failed to reproduce on macOS.

Comment: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=43834